# Avoiding repetitive copy-paste of static_cast<size_t>(enum_type) for casting an enum class to its underlying type

Tags: c++, enums, casting, c++20, enum-class

I have an enum type in my code, like this:

```
enum class GameConsts: size_t { NUM_GHOSTS = 4 };
```

I find myself repeating the required `static_cast` to get the `enum` value:

```
Ghost ghosts[static_cast<size_t>(GameConsts::NUM_GHOSTS)];
// and...
for(size_t i = 0; i < static_cast<size_t>(GameConsts::NUM_GHOSTS); ++i) { ... }
```

**What is the best way to avoid this repetitive `static_cast`?**

The option of allowing implementation of a casting operator was raised in this [ISO proposal discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/g/std-proposals/c/eiN1Xqrt59Y), but seems to drop.

Related SO question: [Overloading cast operator for enum class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166434/overloading-cast-operator-for-enum-class)

---

Davis Herring added in a comment that C++23 added: [std::to_underlying](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_underlying) which should be the answer when we have C++23 compiler support. But the question is for C++20.

Comment: If you're casting enumerations to their underlying type that much, have you considered that maybe you're doing this too often? That maybe you don't really *want* the type safety of an `enum class`?

Comment: @NicolBolas This question comes from my students, they are a bit shy to post it in SO so I did it for them and posted below the answer that I gave. I'll be happy to discuss the answer and see if there are other better alternatives.

Comment: And can you show exactly what goes into that `for` loop? It's fairly likely the whole problem can be trivially avoided with range iteration.

Comment: `std::to_underlying` was added to C++23 in February.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it might be that each ghost gets a different color, based on the index `i`, and yes it can be done with range-based-for probably, but as said above in comment, the question was raised by my students, usually I prefer to answer the question without altering too much their code. And the question is valid and relevant even if the for is replaced, the same casting might be required somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Ok, well, if some enum always has to be casted to a `size_t`, maybe it should not be an enum in the first place. What's the point of having an enum if it always needs to be casted, every time it's used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first option is to use a `constexpr` instead of an enum:

```
constexpr size_t NUM_GHOSTS = 4;
```

You can put it inside a proper context, such as GameConsts struct:

```
struct GameConsts {
    static constexpr size_t NUM_GHOSTS = 4;
};
```

Then there is no need for a casting:

```
Ghost ghosts[GameConsts::NUM_GHOSTS];
```

---

In case you actually need an enum, as you have a list of related values that you want to manage together, then you may use unscoped enum (i.e. drop the `class` from the `enum class` and use a regular plain-old `enum`) but put it inside a struct to preserve the context. I will use here an example of another enum, managing several related values.

```
enum class GameKeys: char { UP = 'W', RIGHT = 'D', DOWN = 'X', LEFT = 'A' };
```

The repeated use of `static_cast` may happen for the above enum, in a switch-case like that:

```
char key_pressed;
// ...
switch(key_pressed) {
    case static_cast<char>(GameKeys::UP): // ...
        break;
    case static_cast<char>(GameKeys::RIGHT): // ...
        break;
    case static_cast<char>(GameKeys::DOWN): // ...
        break;
    case static_cast<char>(GameKeys::LEFT): // ...
        break;
}
```

To avoid the repeated need for `static_cast` you may go with:

---

### Option 1: Use simple unscoped enum inside a struct

```
struct GameKeys {
    enum: char { UP = 'W', RIGHT = 'D', DOWN = 'X', LEFT = 'A' };
};
```

And since old-style enum can cast implicitly to its underlying type, you can get away of the casting:

```
switch(key_pressed) {
    case GameKeys::UP: // ...
        break;
    case GameKeys::RIGHT: // ...
        break;
    case GameKeys::DOWN: // ...
        break;
    case GameKeys::LEFT: // ...
        break;
}
```

---

### Option 2: Add your own conversion function

If you actually prefer, or have to use `enum class` you may have a simple conversion function for which the copy-paste is just calling the function, being less cumbersome than the full `static_cast` syntax:

```
enum class GameKeys: char { UP = 'W', RIGHT = 'D', DOWN = 'X', LEFT = 'A' };

// a simple "val" function - specific for our GameKeys
constexpr char val(GameKeys key) { return static_cast<char>(key); }
```

And:

```
switch(key_pressed) {
    case val(GameKeys::UP): // ...
        break;
    case val(GameKeys::RIGHT): // ...
        break;
    case val(GameKeys::DOWN): // ...
        break;
    case val(GameKeys::LEFT): // ...
        break;
}
```

---

If you choose the last option, you may want to generalize it for any type of `enum`, with [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/150f7731defbb225):

```
// creating a "concept" for enums
template<typename E>
concept EnumType = std::is_enum_v<E>;

// creating a generic "val" function for getting the underlying_type value of an enum
template<EnumType T>
constexpr auto val(T value) {
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(value);
}
```

---

### Option 3: Cast to the enum and not from the enum

As suggested by *[@Nathan Pierson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12334309/nathan-pierson)* and *[@apple apple](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5980430/apple-apple)* in the comments, the casting can be to the enum, with [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99cc885195a8d4a7):

```
char key_pressed = 'E';
// cast to the enum
GameKeys key = static_cast<GameKeys>(key_pressed);
switch(key) {
    case GameKeys::UP: // ...
        break;
    case GameKeys::RIGHT: // ...
        break;
    case GameKeys::DOWN: // ...
        break;
    case GameKeys::LEFT: // ...
        break;
    default: // ignore any other keys
        break;
}
```

This should work fine even if `key_pressed` is not any of the enum values, as we have a fixed enum (having a stated underlying type, note that an enum class is always fixed, even if not stated explicitly). See also: [What happens if you static_cast invalid value to enum class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195312/what-happens-if-you-static-cast-invalid-value-to-enum-class)

Comment: Why do you need a `static_cast<char>` in the `switch` statement in the first place? You can already `switch` on an enum.

Comment: imo you should cast the `char` to `GameKeys` here, not the reverse.

Comment: @NathanPierson the key_pressed char might be any other key stroke (not from the 4 valid enum values) and shall be ignored in such a case. So, casting the pressed char to the enum might _fail_, the code would not become simpler or better I believe.

Comment: @AmirKirsh it would not fail in this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195312/what-happens-if-you-static-cast-invalid-value-to-enum-class;

Comment: @appleapple that's a good ref, I'll apply it into my answer with an additional option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are constantly converting a scoped enum to an integer... you don't actually *want* a scoped enum. What you seem to want is a bunch of `static constexpr` variables in their own namespace:

```
struct GameConsts
{
  static constexpr size_t NumGhosts = 4;
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't need a scoped enum. Just write

```
namespace GameConsts {
    constexpr std::size_t NUM_GHOSTS = 4;
    // Add 'inline' if you can use C++17 or later modes and
    // don't want the declaration to result in multiple objects.
}
```

or

```
struct GameConsts {
    static constexpr std::size_t NUM_GHOSTS = 4;
};
```

### The replacement of `std::to_underlying`

#### C++20

In C++20 you can just write

```
template<class E>
constexpr std::underlying_type_t<E> to_underlying(E e) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
}
```

This implementation is well-constrained as `std::underlying_type` is required to be SFINAE-friendly since C++20.

#### C++11

If you want backport the implementation to C++11 (the first C++ standard revision that has scoped enum), maybe you should write this to avoid undefined behavior in `std::underlying_type`.

```
template<class T, bool = std::is_enum<T>::value>
struct aux_underlying_type {};
template<class E>
struct aux_underlying_type<E, true> {
    static_assert(bool(sizeof(E)), "The template parameter must be a complete enumeration type.");
    using type = typename std::underlying_type<E>::type;
};

template<class E>
using aux_underlying_type_t = typename aux_underlying_type<E>::type;

template<class E>
constexpr aux_underlying_type_t<E> to_underlying(E e) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<aux_underlying_type_t<E>>(e);
}
```